# Truncate multiple tables in SQL Server using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm using SQL Server. I want to create a stored procedure that truncates 3 of my tables (`dbo.table1`, `dbo.table2`, `dbo.table3`).

I want to clear out all of my tables this way. What am I missing?

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE truncate_tables()
  AS
        truncate table dbo.table1
        truncate table dbo.table2
        truncate table dbo.table3
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove `()` next to the stored procedure name. `()` required if you are passing any parameter to the SP.

Add `;` in end of each `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement as query terminator.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE truncate_tables
AS
    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table1;
    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table2;
    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `BEGIN` and `END` and semicolons:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE truncate_tables AS
BEGIN
      truncate table dbo.table1;
      truncate table dbo.table2;
      truncate table dbo.table3;
END;
```

Comment: around my `truncate_tables()` in the `)` section i get a red squiggly line saying that. syntax error: Expecting Variable. What are they talking about?

Comment: @taji01 . . . Also, the empty parentheses are not needed.